# Drag and drop with jquery, button drag and div drop

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I want to implement a solution with jQuery where a button can be dragged to a certain div element. When it gets dropped into that div, it should have customized html.

I found one example which is on jsfiddle, but unfortunate SO does not provide linking to jsfiddle. I am pasting all code here:

HTML

```
<ul id="left-pane">
   <li><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" /></li>
</ul>

<ul id="right-pane">
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#left-pane
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
}

#right-pane
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

JavaScript / jQuery

```
$("#left-pane li").draggable({
    containment: '#gbox',
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone',
    scroll: false,
    connectToSortable: '#right-pane',
    appendTo: '#right-pane',
    start: function () {},
    stop: function (event, ui) {}
}).mousedown(function () {});

$("#right-pane").sortable({
    sort: function () {},
    placeholder: 'ui-state-highlight',
    receive: function () {},
    update: function (event, ui) {}
});

$("#right-pane li").live('dblclick', function () {
    $(this).remove();
})

$("#right-pane").droppable({
    accept: "#left-pane li",
    accept: ":not(.ui-sortable-helper)",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        if ($(ui.draggable).find('.single-item').length == 0)
        {
            $(ui.draggable).append("<div class='single-item'><input type='text' class='item-title' /><br /><textarea class='item-text'></textarea></div>");
        }
    }
});

$("#left-pane").droppable({
    accept: "#right-pane li",
    drop: function (event, ui) {}
});

$("ul, li").disableSelection();
```

I want something similar to the above but I want to change the image into a certain button and rather UI element, can it be changed to normal div?

Could anyone play with this fiddle and provide me a simple drag and drop solution?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can link to fiddle as long as you post code too

Comment: @pete: thanks, it works. I just found solution myself and added the same as answer. I hope it helps other coders too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, I have found the solution myself by playing with the above code. I was doing wrong with the button, because button has already clicked event mapped that is why when I was trying to drag the button it was not working with drag event. I just tried adding div element, which shows like button (styled with css) and it worked like the way I wanted.

Only thing I needed to change is in html code:

```
<ul id="left-pane">
   <li><div align="center" style="width:100px;border:3px solid #ddd; padding:5px;cursor:move;background:#eee;">Drag Me</div>
</ul>

<ul id="right-pane">
</ul>
```

Here is the final solution I was looking: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7RmR/77/